# How do I subtract two images from each other using python and opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, dlib

The objective here is to subtract the mouth from the original image of the face.
Now I know how to crop the mouth using dlib and facial landmarks (which is what this script does).

The question is how do I modify the original image such that it remains entirely the same except without the mouth? Basically I want to cut it out.

```
predictor_path = "/home/victor/facial-landmarks/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat"
faces_folder_path = "/home/victor/TryImage/"
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(predictor_path)
i = 0
for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(faces_folder_path, "*.jpg")):
    print("Processing file: {}".format(f))
    img = cv2.imread(f)

    dets = detector(img, 1)
    print("Number of faces detected: {}".format(len(dets)))
    for k, d in enumerate(dets):
        print("Detection {}: Left: {} Top: {} Right: {} Bottom: {}".format(
            k, d.left(), d.top(), d.right(), d.bottom()))

    shape = predictor(img, d)
    i += 1

    xmouthpoints = [shape.part(x).x for x in range(48,68)]
    ymouthpoints = [shape.part(x).y for x in range(48,68)]
    maxx = max(xmouthpoints)
    minx = min(xmouthpoints)
    maxy = max(ymouthpoints)
    miny = min(ymouthpoints)

    pad = 10

    filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f))[0]

    crop_image = img[(miny-pad):(maxy+pad),(minx-pad):(maxx+pad)]
    img = cv2.subtract(img, crop_image)
    imshow(crop_image, 1)
    imshow(new_image, 1)

    cv2.imwrite(str(filename) + '.jpg',crop_image)
```

Using cv2.subtract yields the following error: error: OpenCV(3.4.1) /io/opencv/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:659: error: (-209) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function arithm_op

I've also thought about using image subtraction, is that possible?

Even if it will be some black or white box or circle instead of the mouth, it'd be perfect.

Note: I would use GIMP or Photoshop, but I'm dealing with thousands of selfies, so it's not really an option.

Thank you : )

The image I am using is attached here.

[My selfie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezOY1.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your error says, OpenCV subtract is expecting 2 images with identical shape. In your case you give a big image and a smaller one, how will OpenCV know what part of the big image to subtract?

Then again, it looks like you want to remove the mouth, and it will have in it's place just black pixels. You can achieve the same result with:

```
cv2.rectangle(img, ((minx-pad), (miny-pad)), ((maxx-pad), (maxy-pad)), (0,0,0), -1)
```

or even with numpy directly:

```
img[(miny-pad):(maxy+pad),(minx-pad):(maxx+pad)] = 0
```

or if you really want to use subtract :

```
crop_image = img[(miny-pad):(maxy+pad),(minx-pad):(maxx+pad)]
img[(miny-pad):(maxy+pad),(minx-pad):(maxx+pad)] = cv2.subtract(img[(miny-pad):(maxy+pad),(minx-pad):(maxx+pad)], crop_image)
```

In this last one you are telling subtract: What part of the image to subtract and where to put the result once done. I would recommend option number 2, the numpy directly way.

On doubt, just leave me a comment

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, but I may have not been specific enough. What I want is for the original pic to look something like this: https://i.imgur.com/8OMtgQ8.jpg . So basically the original pic stays invariably the same except that the mouth is blacked out as in the image I just linked. And of course, it must still work for several images at once

Comment: Nevermind, I just tried the first method. It worked perfectly.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance! Appreciate it!

Comment: @VictorSimon Sure no problem. To delete the exact mouth region you can use a mask and the binaryAnd function

Comment: I'm tying to do it via convex hull and facial landmarks right now, but I don't know if that's a good method too.

Comment: @VictorSimon if you have the points of the mouth (and I think you have it in `xmouthpoints` and `ymouthpoints`, you can create a mask (black is not mouth and white is mouth) with the size of your cropped image. Then you can use the subtract method in my answer, but using the mask in the function `cv2.subtract(img[(miny-pad):(maxy+pad),(minx-pad):(maxx+pad)], crop_image, mask=maskImage)` and then it should delete only the points of the mouth.